# Adding Multiple files into Winrar archive with Powershell

Tags: powershell, winrar

I have a script that used to work and add multiple files to a Winrar archive, test the archive, then delete the original files.  It worked great, then I broke it, and now cannot fix.
problem now is that for each file I am adding to the archive, a new Winrar window pops up and tells me that a file is in use by another process.

The powershell here is likely fine, but I think i'm doing something wrong with the rar command and/or the paths.

thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
    set-alias rar "c:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe"
$startdate = get-date("7/20/2015 00:00")
$enddate = get-date("7/21/2015 00:00")
$path = "D:\TFS.Backup"
$files = Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {$_.creationtime -gt $startdate -and $_.creationtime -lt $enddate}
$filedate = $startdate.day
$fileyear = $startdate.year
$filemonth = $startdate.month
$rarname = "$fileyear-$filemonth-$filedate.rar"
$destination = "$path\archive"
foreach ($file in $files) {rar  a -r -m3 -t -df -mt4 $destination\$rarname $path\$file}
```

Comment: Try using something like Handle to see what's keeping that file open. You can download Handle from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx

Comment: I am pretty sure that winrar is trying to add to archive while another winrar thread is writing to it.. the million winrar popup windows - one for each file in $files are what's cluing me in to that. when the script worked properly, the files were added to the archive in sequence, inside execution window, or in the background, when the script was executed with task scheduler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use `$file.fullname` instead of `$path\$file`, for better practice. And second, use `rar.exe` not `winrar.exe` to archive via command line, because `rar.exe` is a console application, and it does not release the script to continue to the next file until this file would be added to the archive. Also it might be needed to use `&` before `rar`.

Comment: Yes, Thank you!  using winrar.exe vs rar.exe was the problem!